# Gradient stroke along canvas arc disappearing when context translates to center

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, linear-gradients

I am very new to canvas drawings. I am trying to apply gradient along the arc of a circle. I can get it to appear fine when I draw the arc with center offset from the context coordinates. Lets say centerX and centerY denote the center of the canvas. I can get a gradient arc using `context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, ......)`.

```
Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/m5Pmb/
```

But when I try to draw the arc around the context coordinates, the gradient disappears. For example, I take the above working jsfiddle example, do `context.translate(centerX, centerY)`, then do `context.arc(0,0,radius,......)`, the resulting arc does not have any gradient on it.

```
Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/N6NMB/
```

In my case, I need to spin the resulting circle around its axis using context.rotate(), so I must translate to the center and draw circle around (0,0). But I cant understand why the gradient disappears when trying to draw arc around context's (0,0) point. Any insight would be really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are translating the context `centerX` and `centerY` are not where you think anymore.

When you translate the context you are saying you want that x and y to be the new 0,0. So now your 0,0 is in the center of the canvas, so `centerX` and `centerY` are offset by themselves putting them further away from the center.

One method you can use is the following

```
var grad = context.createLinearGradient(
    -radius,
    radius / 2,
    radius,
    radius / 2
);
```

**[live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/N6NMB/2/)**

The above works because its called *after* you translate the context, so `centerX` and `centerY` (like I said previously) are 0,0 meaning they don't need to be referenced in that function.

Answer (score 2):

The gradients that you create will be painted with the actual transform in use.

So if you are not using any transform, no need to wonder anything : define your gradient where you're about to draw, and you'll be fine.

If you are using transform, you must think of the coordinates of the gradient as relative to the point/angle/scale when you'll use them.

To explain further, i modified your example and used a radial gradient.
I created a normalized gradient : it is defined in between 0.0 and 1.0 radius, meaning it will have its x and y in [-1; 1].

```
var eyeGrad = context.createRadialGradient(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0);
```

Then to use the gradient i must :
1) translate to be in the center of the figure i want to draw.
2) scale to have normalized coordinates.

```
function drawEye(x, y, r) {
    context.save();
    //translate context to center
    context.translate(x, y);
    // scale to radius
    context.scale(r, r);
    context.beginPath();
    // draw an arc with radius of 1
    context.arc(0, 0, 1, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fillStyle = eyeGrad;
    context.fill();
    context.restore();
}
```

fiddle is here :

```
   http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/N6NMB/3/
```

Result for :

```
drawEye(100, 100, 40);
drawEye(250, 120, 20);
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why did you use scale? I tried removing the scale and using radius while drawing arc e.g. context.arc(0,0,r,2*Math.PI,false). But all it drew was a 1px radius circle. Why would it draw such a small circle despite big radius value?

Comment: the idea is to use the same coordinates system as the gradient. So first thing is to center, then you scale to use normalized ([0,1]) coordinates.

Comment: ah damn I'm going to have to up my game on all my newer answers @GameAlchemist is including screenshots and more thought out code :P +1